# Short story regarding aliens who come to Earth to answer a question humanity has

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

No it's not "The Last Question" nor is it "The Last Answer" so don't bother.

I don't remember the rest if the plot if there is one, but the main part of the short story is that enlightened aliens arrive on Earth and offer to answer humanity's questions. I'm almost certain it was aliens and not a deity. I don't remember if the number of questions was limited.

Paraphrased, the question humanity asks is:

> What would be the best question for us to ask?

And the answer, also paraphrased, is:

> The question they just asked.

Also I appologize if this is a duplicate, Google didn't return much relevant and I'm on mobile so SE doesn't provide potential duplicates as you type.

Comment: Here's the version of this old joke that I heard 50 or 60 years ago: A man goes on an arduous pilgrimage to consult an all-knowing sage who would respond to one question. On finding the sage, the man asks him, "What is the best question that I can ask, and what is the best answer that can be given?" The sage replies, "The best question that can be asked is the one you have just asked, and the best answer that can be given is the one I am giving you." Apparently somebody took this old story and dressed it up with aliens.

Comment: I found a version of this Zen koan (or whatever it is) on the web: [“What is the Ultimate Question, and what is its Answer?”. The answer to that is, of course: “The Ultimate Question is ‘What is the Ultimate Question, and what is its Answer?’ and its answer is what has just been given.”](http://www.madore.org/~david/misc/totipsism.html)

Comment: @user14111 now that you mention it, it's possible this was just a joke I heard (but with aliens instead of a wise sage). Though I'm pretty sure that link you posted wasn't it.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse (aliens asking humanity a question) appears in a block quotation at the start of chapter two of "The Alien IQ Test", by Clifford A. Pickover, the quotation is attributed to Clifford A. Pickover as well.

The quote is:

> If an alien comes to you and asks, "What is the most important question we can ask humanity and what is the best possible answer you can give?,", the safest reply is, "You have just asked the most important question you can ask humanity,
> and I'm giving you the best possible answer."

I also thought that I had read that phrase in a short story, but I'm pretty sure I have never read anything by Pickover.